# What is the meaning of "a circuit to" in the following sentences?

Tags: meaning

What is the meaning of "a circuit to" in the following sentences,

> Resistance is a measure of the opposition of **a circuit to** the flow
>   of a steady current, while impedance takes into account not only the
>   resistance but also dynamic  effects (known as reactance).

( Source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Admittance )

Does "Resistance is a measure of the opposition of **a circuit to** the flow of a steady current" mean "Resistance is a measure of the opposition of **a circuit that is** the flow of a steady current"?

Does "a circuit to the flow " mean " a circuit that is the flow" ? If so (a cirucit = the flow ), does "**to**" in "a circuit to the flow" mean "**that is**" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does "Resistance is a measure of the opposition of a circuit to the flow of a steady current" mean "Resistance is a measure of the opposition of a circuit that is the flow of a steady current"?

No.  You're analyzing the sentence incorrectly.  The preposition "to" belongs to "opposition"; if you are preventing me from going inside then you are acting in opposition to me.

Try this:

> Resistance is a measure (of the opposition) (of a circuit) (to the flow of a steady current).

Alternatively, it could be reworded using the possessive:

> Resistance is a measure of a circuit's opposition to the flow of a steady current.